# A question about controlling pm DC motor with long signal wires

Tags: dc, pwm

I have a PWM driver board for a 12V pm DC motor(like toy motors) to control its speed. To create a shake effect the motor will be mounted 50 meters far away from the PWM driver board, for such long wiring is there any extra practice for such application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resistance of the 50 meters of wire needs to be considered. The resulting voltage drop may require a higher power supply voltage. The speed variation due to load variation may be greater than it would be with less voltage drop. You need to know how much current the motor requires and how much resistance is added by the wire. You may need to use a larger wire if the voltage drop is too much.